# How to automatically generate Checkboxes in a grid (vertical and horizontal)

Tags: c#, checkbox

I am trying to programmatically generate a grid of checkboxes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaZgC.jpg).

Here is what I got so far:

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox[] c = new CheckBox[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < c.Length; j++)
            {
                c[i] = new CheckBox();
                c[j] = new CheckBox();

                c[i].Location = new Point(5, i * 20);
                c[j].Location = new Point(j * 20, 20);
                this.Controls.Add(c[i]);
                this.Controls.Add(c[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Fixed spelling and clarity in title; usage of "got" vs. "have"; indented code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a flaw in your loops. You have to create only one at the time, iterating either through the columns, then the rows, or the other way around.

It doesn't make sense to create two checkboxes each iteration though. Also, I don't think you need to store the checkboxes in an array.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfRows = 2;
    int numberOfColumns = 5;

    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
        {
            var checkbox = new CheckBox();

            checkbox.Location = new Point(20 * col, 20 * row);
            this.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this should produce the expected behavior.

Comment: I have got just 2 Row without the 5 Columns

Comment: There was a typo, it should work now. You can take a look at this snippet : http://csharppad.com/gist/21110fce1c07e6209bbc2bcb9949057a. We see that all the positions are generated.

Comment: still not working           `for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                {
                    int index = row * numberOfColumns + col;
                    var checkbox = new CheckBox();
                
                    checkbox.Location = new Point(20 * col, 20 * row);
                
                    this.Controls.Add(checkbox);`

Comment: I suspect that you have a problem elsewhere or that your values of  numberOfRows and numberOfColums are invalid. For example, your chexkboxes could be creates but overlapping, so you can only see two checkboxes. Put a breakpoint in the loop, see if the checkboxes are actually created, etc.

Comment: is there a way to do it with 2D Array?

Comment: I think the Checkboxes were created but they are not visible